# Dynamically set field choices for article

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Using apostrophe-blog, I've added several custom fields in `lib\modules\apostrophe-blog\index.js`. One of these fields is a `select` list. However, I need to dynamically populate the list values based on other properties of the article being edited. Currently, I'm trying this, but the admin modal stops working, so this doesn't look like it will work:

```
module.exports = {
    contextual: true,
    addFields: [
      {
        type: 'select',
        name: 'featuredIn',
        label: 'Featured In:',
        choices: []
      },
      construct: function (self, options) {
          self.pageBeforeSend = (req, callback) => {
            var featuredIn = self.options.addFields.find(x => x.name === 'featuredIn');
           featuredIn.choices = []; //do a lookup from db - self.apos.docs.find(req, { id: ?})
            return callback(null);

          }
      }
  };
```

Is there another approach to doing this? Currently, I'm not sure what event would I hook into to set these values, and also where I would retrieve the article id for the article being edited - `self.apos.docs.find(req, { id: ?})`. Thanks in advance for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know I am the lead developer of Apostrophe at P'unk Avenue.

I believe you're trying to associate one piece type with another. This is a built-in feature; you just want a join.

You don't say what type of doc is being featured, and what other type of doc it's being "featured in." Already this is confusing to write about (: So let me give you an example:

- You have "shops" that sell stuff.
- You have "products." Each product might be featured in one "shop."
- Both are "apostrophe-pieces" subclasses, but keep in mind the techniques below work for page types too.

SHOP SCHEMA

```
addFields: [
  {
    name: '_products',
    type: 'joinByArray',
    label: 'Featured:',
    withType: 'product',
    idsField: 'productIds',
    sortable: true
  }
]
```

Boom... that's it. When you edit a shop, you automatically get a field allowing you to autocomplete the names of products and select them. And then when you are viewing a shop, you will find that the `._products` property is populated for you.

The `idsField` property is just a mongodb property that will store the actual array of chosen product ids. You can give it any name but we recommend this naming convention.

NOTE: you must use a leading `_` for a join's `name`. If you don't the join winds up stored in the database, which is redundant and also almost immediately out of date. The `_` means "I am a dynamic, temporary property, don't store me. I'll get calculated again every time I am needed."

#### Accessing the shops from the product side

So far so good. But sometimes you have a product and you want to know what shops it is featured in. No problem:

PRODUCT SCHEMA

```
addFields: [
  {
    name: '_shops',
    type: 'joinByArrayReverse',
    label: 'Featured In:',
    withType: 'shop',
    idsField: 'productIds'
  }
]
```

This is a "reverse join." It makes a `_shops` array available any time you have a `product` object. It works by locating the shops that include this product in their `productIds` array.

You cannot edit a join from the reverse end. If that's the end where you want to do the editing, just change which party has `joinByArray` and which party has `joinByArrayReverse`.

Hope this is helpful!

Also see our [schema guide](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/schema-guide.html) which covers joins in detail.

Comment: FYI, you can join with any doc type name; pages are allowed too, not just pieces. And you can set `withType` to `apostrophe-page` if you wish to join with *any* type of page in the tree (not a piece).

Comment: Thanks Tom. I'm trying to achieve this join: 
 aposDocs T1, aposDocs T2 join T1.title = T2.tags(array).name 
 Where t1.type = 'apostrophe-blog-page' AND t1.level = 1. Using the object below, I have a join on pages, but it is not limiting the pages to level 1. How might I do this? Thanks.
  {
      name: '_title',
      type: 'joinByOne',
      withType: 'apostrophe-blog-page',
      label: 'Primary',
      idField: 'pageId',
      required: true,
      filters: {
        projection: {
          title: 1,
          slug: 1,
          level: 1
        }
      }
    }

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to add the filters option to limit the query results? I'm trying this (and several combos) but it doesnt limit the result as I expect.  {
      name: '_tags',
      type: 'joinByOne',
      withType: 'apostrophe-blog-page',
      label: 'Feature In',
      idField: 'featuredInPageId',
      filters: {
        criteria: {
          level:'1' 
        }
      }
    }

Comment: Re-reading the answer, this tells me how to pull relationships via a db join, but what if I wanted to do something else to the data (for example, read some data from a json file and inject options from this file as select list field values)? How can the fields be dynamically updated based on custom logic that needs to be implemented outside of a db relationship or a relationship tied to other pieces?

Comment: Hmm, you might have more luck with:

    filters: { and: { level: 1 } }

"Level" is an integer (not a string), and the "and" filter merges with existing criteria rather than blowing them out.

Comment: As for your more general question: 

http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/custom-schema-field-types.html

With this you can build a schema field type that does anything you please, including async calls. Have fun!

Comment: In lib\modules\apostrophe-blog\index.js, I have this object in addFields array. Shouldn't this code limit the choices to apostrophe-blog-page records where level is 1? addFields: [
    {
      name: '_tags',
      type: 'joinByOne',
      withType: 'apostrophe-blog-page',
      label: 'Feature In',
      idField: 'featuredInPageId',
      filters: {
        and: {
          level: 1
        }
      }
    }. This still doesn't limit the options  to  apostrophe-blog-page records where level is 1. Is this a bug or do I still have a syntax error? Thanks.